# Django migration dependency order

Tags: django, django-models

I have a relatively complex set of Django models. I'm trying to start with a fresh set of migrations (`rm -rf apps/*/migrations; bin/dev/manage.py makemigrations A B C...`). `makemigrations` works fine, and there are no circular dependencies, but I'm consistently getting an `InconsistentMigrationHistory` exception when I migrate. Here's a graph of the dependencies between the migrations, simplified to remove the migrations with no related dependencies, and with the app names redacted for readability:
[image: Migration dependencies]
 The links in red cause the error (different ones each time I run `migrate`), even with a `run_before` added to each migration that should be run before its dependency:

A/migrations/0002_whatever.py:

```
...
run_before = [('P', '0001_initial'),]
```

Here's the error text.

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration `P.migrations.0001_initial` is applied before its dependency `A.migrations.0002_whatever` on database 'default'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to reset database also right?

Comment: Hmm. After dropping the database and recreating it, migrate works.

Comment: Thought so, without removing the Database, you removed the migrations. So when you try to migrate, django will find your database state and your migrations inconsistant

Comment: Hi @ScottDeerwester, have you created the graph by yourself or is there any tool to generate the dependency graph?

Comment: I used the dot language, which is part of the graphviz package. Very straightforward.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to reset the database as well.

When you created new migrations without resetting the database, the sync between your database and migrations was lost.

So when you try to migrate the new migrations, Django will find it inconsistent and fail.

It is generally not a good idea to clear all migrations and generate new migrations for the same reason.

Imagine this happening in production.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is a system in heavy development, so the case for starting the migrations over is, while unusual, not unreasonable. We would, of course, never consider something like this in production.